# oracle sequence match & exact word match for a column

Tags: oracle

currently matching with UTL_MATCH.jaro_winkler_similarity (upper(colname),upper(variablename)) jws.
how to achieve sequence match & exact word match?

Comment: It would help if you posted some sample input data and told us how you're expecting to match it.

Comment: select UTL_MATCH.jaro_winkler_similarity (upper('bala'),upper('alampur')) jws from dual; is output 72. 'bala' and 'bala subramanian' can have matches but not  'bala' and  'alampur'. so i want to perform sequence & exact word match.

Comment: that is similarity on words not on part of word

Comment: You need to give an abstract definition of "match" (for your specific real-life problem). Examples are good, but they do not count as a complete "definition". For example: does the word "mother" match "chemotherapy"? Before you say "no", notice that the word "mother" appears exactly in "che**mother**apy". I didn't just make up this example right now; the problem is known as the "*mother is in chemotherapy* problem".

Answer (score 0):

That's exact match, then. Is it not? Then you just have to compare `colname` to `variablename`, directly, e.g.

```
if colname = variablename then
   -- that's exact match, do something
```

Comment: is there any matching  technique in oracle other than jaro_similarity, edit similarity, like and equal to

Comment: See whether SOUNDEX helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace FUNCTION NUMOFSEQWORDS 
(
  P_STR1 IN VARCHAR2 
, P_STR2 IN VARCHAR2 
) RETURN NUMBER AS 
    l_str1     varchar2(4000) := p_str1;
    l_str2     varchar2(4000) := p_str2;
    l_res      number  default 0;
    l_del_pos1 number;
    l_del_pos2 number;
    l_word1    varchar2(1000);
    l_word2    varchar2(1000);
    l_word_cnt number;
    l_word_cnt1 number;
    l_word_cnt2 number;
    l_word_weight number:=0;
    l_jws number:=0;
BEGIN

select regexp_count(l_str1, '[^ ]+') into l_word_cnt1 from dual;
select regexp_count(l_str2, '[^ ]+') into l_word_cnt2 from dual;
l_word_cnt:=LEAST(l_word_cnt1,l_word_cnt2);
--l_word_cnt:=greatest(l_word_cnt1,l_word_cnt2);
l_word_weight:=100.0/l_word_cnt;
   begin
    loop
      l_del_pos1 := instr(l_str1, ' ');
      l_del_pos2 := instr(l_str2, ' ');
      case l_del_pos1
        when 0 
        then l_word1 := l_str1;
             l_str1 := ''; 
        else l_word1 := substr(l_str1, 1, l_del_pos1 - 1);
      end case;
      case l_del_pos2
        when 0 
        then l_word2 := l_str2;
             l_str2 := ''; 
        else l_word2 := substr(l_str2, 1, l_del_pos2 - 1);
      end case;
      exit when (l_word1 <> l_word2) or 
                ((l_word1 is null) or (l_word2 is null));

      if (l_word1 = l_word2) then
      l_res := l_res + 1;        
      end if;
      l_str1 := substr(l_str1, l_del_pos1 + 1);
      l_str2 := substr(l_str2, l_del_pos2 + 1);
    end loop;
    --return l_res;
    return l_res*l_word_weight;
  end;

END NUMOFSEQWORDS;
```

I ended up creating function above to find the match weightage between two strings
We can use LEAST or greatest to find weightage